# Pyside2, How to avoid .parent().parent().parent().parent()

Tags: python, design-patterns, signals-slots, pyside2

So I have a simple pyside2 app where I want a button to update a counter widget.

The button has been subclassed and has a function that calls the increment function of the counter widget.

Currently call looks like this

```
self.parent().parent().parent().parent().counter_widget.increment()
```

This is pretty ugly. How should I make this call between widgets that are are so distant in the class hierarchy.

Comment: I think that your approach is not correct(at least not elegant), if you provide a [MRE] the community you could analyze a more elegant solution such as the use of signal-slots, QEvents, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could either pass the object you want to reference to the other object and then access the attribute directly. If you want to simply make the syntax nicer you can add the following method:

```
def up(self, levels):
    if levels < 0:
        raise ValueError('cannot go up negative levels')
    obj = self
    while levels > 0:
        obj = obj.parent()
        levels -= 1
    return obj
```

then instead of

```
self.parent().parent().parent().parent().counter_widget.increment()
```

you can simply write:

```
self.up(4).counter_widget.increment()
```

I hope this was helpful!